# Create .BPMN2.0.xml from Java

Tags: java, xml, api, bpmn, activiti

I need to create my process using Java.
The idea is to read data from db, and consequently personalize the process with these informations.

For example i could create a form in my task with a combo box loaded with infos extract from the sql query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use or extend the [activiti designer](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ACT/Activiti+Designer+Developer+Guide) for eclipse. It's open source and maybe you can design an extension to load your data from your db.